# JSON parse where key is a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON but one of the keys is a url and I think this is causing problems. I'm using the below:

```
$(data.query.results.json).each(function() {
    console.log(this.http:__capitadiscovery.co.uk_-ac_items_1743268);
});
```

Is there any way round this?

Comment: What is `this.http:__capitadiscovery.co.uk_-ac_items_1743268`?  The colon and several other characters will throw an unexpected token error.

Comment: show the JSON and explain what you want to output in the console..

Comment: So the key is `http:__capitadiscovery.co.uk_-ac_items_1743268`? If so, use `this["http:__capitadiscovery.co.uk_-ac_items_1743268"]`

Comment: Yes I see that but 'http:__capitadiscovery.co.uk_-ac_items_1743268' is the key of the JSON object and I have no way of changing it.

Comment: @podusmonens no one said you had to change it.